# android how to get xml files from an apk

Tags: android

I am trying read all xml files from apk but i unable to do that.
I am using `apktool` for that but it still unreadable.

How can i read that, please any one give me all the step by step process.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).

Usage: `java -jar apktool.jar d yourapk.apk`

Also have a look at this script: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695701 It's able of batch decompiling, which makes it really easy to have a closer look at apk files.

Comment: baksmali doesn't deal with xml files :)

Comment: Oh you're right ^^ I use script for decompiling that uses apktool (and baksmali obviously, as it is a part of apktool).
I added the link to the anwwer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question but an APK is basically a zipped file, you can use any unzip tool to open it and read the contents.

Comment: ya u can unzip that, but that files are unreadable. So for that we hav to do somthing

Answer (score 0):

I think this tool can be useful to you, **[android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)**,but as I have never used this You will have to try it yourself.

And to know the Java class files use this **[dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)**

If you find any difficluty in using these,please try search on Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Getting xml files from apk

Download apktool and apktool install from the link and extract both files and place it in the same folder (for example "demoxmlfolder").
Place the .apk file in same folder (i.e demoxmlfolder)
Now open command prompt and goto  the directory where apktool is stored (here "demoxmlfolder") and type the command "apktool if framework-res.apk" 
Above command should result in "Framework installed ..."
Now in command prompt type the command "apktool d filename.apk" (where filename is name of apk file)
This will generate a folder of name filename in current directory (here demoxmlfolder) where all xml files would be stored in res\layout folder.
Links : https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool-install-windows-r04-brut1.tar.bz2
and
https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool1.4.1.tar.bz2&can=2&q=